# "@typescript-eslint/no-useless-template-literals" vs "prefer-template" conflict in ESLint

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

```js
Logger.logInfo({
  //...
  description:
      `${ this.TARGET_SOURCE_FILES_TYPE__SINGULAR_FORM__CAPITALIZED } file has been added.\n` +
      `${ targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath }`
});
```

I have

> ESLint: Template literal expression is unnecessary and can be simplified.
> (@typescript-eslint/no-useless-template-literals)

---

With

```js
Logger.logInfo({
  // ...
  description:
      `${ this.TARGET_SOURCE_FILES_TYPE__SINGULAR_FORM__CAPITALIZED } file has been added.\n` +
      targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath
});
```

I have

> ESLint: Unexpected string concatenation.(prefer-template)

Same for

```js
Logger.logInfo({
  // ...
  description:
      this.TARGET_SOURCE_FILES_TYPE__SINGULAR_FORM__CAPITALIZED +
      " file has been added.\n" +
      targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath
});
```

---

```js
Logger.logInfo({
  // ...
  description:
      `${ this.TARGET_SOURCE_FILES_TYPE__SINGULAR_FORM__CAPITALIZED } file has been added.\n ${ targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath } `
});
```

is too long. Depending on `max-len` rule configuration (130 columns in my case), this rule could be violated. And, the single template string exploded to multiple lines causes the extra spaces (in my case before `${ targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath }`). AFAIK there is no elegant solution.

```js
Logger.logInfo({
  // ...
  description:
      `${ this.TARGET_SOURCE_FILES_TYPE__SINGULAR_FORM__CAPITALIZED } file has been updated.\n
      ${ targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath }`
});
```

How to resolve this conflict?
It is actual for below versions of ESLint and it's plugings:

- `eslint`: 8.56.0
- `@typescript-eslint/*`: 7.0.2

Hope I can avoid the filling of became too long issue templates in GitHub repos.

Answer (score 1):

The rule `@typescript-eslint/no-useless-template-literals` is failing in first snippet because the interpolation for variable `targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath` is useless.

Do it this way:

```
Logger.logInfo({
  //...
  description: `${ this.TARGET_SOURCE_FILES_TYPE__SINGULAR_FORM__CAPITALIZED } file has been added.
${ targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath }`
  });
}
```

No need to explicitly add a newline. Template literals are multiline strings.

If that's still hitting your maxlen limit consider using a [line continuation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/tivoli-netcoolimpact/6.1.0?topic=fundamentals-line-continuation-character)

```
Logger.logInfo({
  //...
  description: `${ this.TARGET_SOURCE_FILES_TYPE__SINGULAR_FORM__CAPITALIZED } \
file has been added.
${ targetFileOrDirectoryAbsolutePath }`
});
```

I've set a max-len of 80 in this example. [check it on eslint playground](https://eslint.org/play/#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)